# Parse date/time from string?

Tags: java, string, parsing, date, time

I'm trying to create a program to parse a meaningful date and time from a string. I want to be able to give the following kinds of input, and create a date/time object:

```
5 o'clock
5 p.m.
5 a.m.
5
530
530 a.m.
530 p.m.
Tuesday at [insert any above string here]
the 30th at [same as above]
May 12th at [same as above]
today at [same as above]
tomorrow at [same as above]
```

Any string that doesn't contain a day/date can be assumed as being today, and any time that does not have an AM/PM designation can be assumed as occuring between 9AM and 8:59PM.
I quickly realized what a mess this was becoming after writing this portion of code:

```
private void createEvent(String phrase) {
    int hour;
    int day = 0;
    String dayOfWeek = "";

    if (phrase.contains("o'clock")) {
        hour = Integer.parseInt(phrase.substring(phrase.indexOf("o'clock")-3, phrase.indexOf("o'clock")-1).trim());
        out.write(""+hour);
    }

    if (phrase.contains("tomorrow"))
        day = (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK % 7)+1;

    if (phrase.contains("sunday") || day == 1) {
        dayOfWeek = "Sunday"; day = 1; }
    else if (phrase.contains("monday") || day == 2) {
        dayOfWeek = "Monday"; day = 2; }
    else if (phrase.contains("tuesday") || day == 3) {
        dayOfWeek = "Tuesday"; day = 3; }
    else if (phrase.contains("wednesday") || day == 4) {
        dayOfWeek = "Wednesday"; day = 4; }
    else if (phrase.contains("thursday") || day == 5) {
        dayOfWeek = "Thursday"; day = 5; }
    else if (phrase.contains("friday") || day == 6) {
        dayOfWeek = "Friday"; day = 6; }
    else if (phrase.contains("saturday") || day == 7) {
        dayOfWeek = "Saturday"; day = 7; }
    else {
        dayOfWeek = "Today"; day = 0; }     
}
```

Can anyone provide some direction?

Comment: I would focus on each case seperatly, maybe creating a simple `Formatter` for the basic purpose.  The add them all to a central `FormatFactory`.  This would allow you to grow the potential number of formatters as you need (or exclude some if you needed to)

Comment: What else is likely to be in your strings?  Will the whole string pertain to time, or might some portion of it contain other information?  Example: "I'll meet you by the station at 5 o'clock"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break your problem down into manageable chunks...

I would start by providing a means by which you can add new formatters as you need.

I would also try and find away to reuse existing code.  Time is a pretty consistent aspect to your problem.

This would lead me to the concept of providing a centralised format factory of some kind (make the management easier), but break down the individual requirements into smaller manageable chunks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomDateFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CustomDateFormatter();
    }

    public CustomDateFormatter() {

        String values[] = new String[]{
            "5 o'clock",
            "5 p.m.",
            "5 a.m.",
            "5",
            "530",
            "530 a.m.",
            "530 p.m.",};

        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println(value + " = " + CustomFormatFactory.format(value));
        }
    }

    public static class CustomFormatFactory {

        private static List<CustomFormat> formatters = new ArrayList<>();

        public static Date format(String value) {
            Date date = null;
            for (CustomFormat format : formatters) {
                if (format.canFormat(value)) {
                    date = format.format(value);
                    if (date != null) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return date;
        }

        protected static boolean formatTime(String value, Calendar cal) {
            boolean formatted = false;
            if (Character.isDigit(value.charAt(0))) {
                formatted = true;
                StringBuilder timePart = new StringBuilder(4);
                int index = 0;
                while (index < value.length() && Character.isDigit(value.charAt(index))) {
                    timePart.append(value.charAt(index));
                    index++;
                }

                int hour = 0;
                int min = 0;
                if (timePart.length() < 3) {
                    hour = Integer.parseInt(timePart.toString());
                } else {
                    hour = Integer.parseInt(timePart.substring(0, timePart.length() - 2));
                    min = Integer.parseInt(timePart.substring(timePart.length() - 2, 3));
                }

                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                String sufix = value.substring(timePart.length()).trim();
                if ("p.m.".equalsIgnoreCase(sufix) || "pm".equalsIgnoreCase(sufix)) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
                }
            }
            return formatted;
        }

        static {
            formatters.add(new SimpleTimeFormat());
        }
    }

    public static interface CustomFormat {

        public boolean canFormat(String value);

        public Date format(String value);
    }

    public static class SimpleTimeFormat implements CustomFormat {

        @Override
        public boolean canFormat(String value) {
            return format(value) != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Date format(String value) {
            Date date = null;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (CustomFormatFactory.formatTime(value, cal)) {
                date = cal.getTime();
            }
            return date;
        }
    }
}
```

For the extended date formats, I would extract the date portions, build a `Calendar` based on the dates, extract the time partitions as a separate `String` and use the `CustomFormatFactory.formatTime` method to format the time, thus, saving your self the hassel of having to recode it each time.

Equally, the date formatters could simple have a instance of a time formatter internally or you could set up the factory to have multiple format methods, one that takes a time value and loops through the available time formatters ... this would be my personal choice ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use DateFormat

```
String now = new Date().toString();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(now);
```

Maybe you could build a few format in advance, then compare the parsed dates.

check tutorial here: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142

Comment: Won't parse "a.m." or "p.m." and what about "tomorrow"?

Comment: It's impossible to write code to handle every situation if the string format has no limitation. If you want to parse everything the user input, it will become a problem about natural language processing...